# When I import Paypal Button and use it, so I get these buttons two time but I am using it for once

Tags: reactjs, paypal

When I import  Paypal Button and use it, so I get these buttons two time but I am using it for once as you can see in my code i am just it one time why does it show me two times, infact both forms working correctly, when i inspect it it showed me the same two div with the same id of button in parent div. but how to fix it?
this is my code:

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
    import styled from "styled-components"
    const PayPalButton = window.paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });
    
    function Paypal() {
      const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [
            {
              amount: {
                value: "0.01",
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      }
      const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.capture();
      }
      return (
        <PaypalBG>
          <div className="paypal-wrapper">
            <PayPalButton
              createOrder={(data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)}
              onApprove={(data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)}
            />
          </div>
        </PaypalBG>
      )
    }
    
    const PaypalBG = styled.div`
      width: 100vw;
      min-height: 100vh;
      background-color: gray;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      .paypal-wrapper{
        padding: 100px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: white;
    
      }
    
    export default Paypal
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvlqi.png)

---

Answer (score 0):

Start over with a better example using the newer official [@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default)